# How do I use this JWT token once I have it on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I am trying to create login functionality using JWT Tokens. I have spent countless hours researching this topic and I am still struggling. Here is where I am at so far.

My login API

```
const loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {username, password} = req.body
        //grabbing user associated with our username
        const user = await User.findOne({username:username}) 
        //check if username and password come from the same user
        if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))){
            console.log(user)
            res.status(200).json({
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                token: generateToken(user._id)
            })
        } else {
            res.status(400)
            throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}

//get JWT token
const generateToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
}
```

My front-end fetch request for the login form

```
const loginSubmit = async () => {
        const loginForm = document.getElementById('login_form') //grabbing the login_form
        const data = new URLSearchParams() // this can take in form data
        //this for loop runs for each input field for the form passed into FormData()
        for (const pair of new FormData(loginForm)){
            data.append(pair[0], pair[1]) //pair[0] is the name of the input, pair[1] is the value
        }
        const response = await fetch('/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data //passing the form data into our req.body
        })
        const {token} = await response.json()
        console.log(token)
    }
```

My route protection function to check the authorization header and verify the token

```
const authUser = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
        if (token == null){
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error('Not authorized')
        }
        jtw.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(403)
                throw new Error('User does not have access')
                req.user = user
            }
        })
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
    
}
```

I am really just trying to understand how all of this ties together. For example, my authorization function works, but it only works if the token is passed into the authorization header. Where in my code would I explicitly put the token into the header?

Another question, once I have the token on the front-end, what exactly do I do with it to create a unique experience for each user? I have done this with passport basic username and password login functionality, but I am trying to recreate that type of experience using JWT.

I have the token on the front-end but its not in the authorization header, would I place it there on the front-end to protect future routes? Is the secure?

I don't know, any resources / help on this would be so awesome!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Two words: `fetch interceptor`. Do NOT try to retrieve and pass this token everywhere you are making a request. Write a single fetch interceptor that adds this token to the header of relevant requests (which is often all of them for a specific domain).

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to store it

1. store it in the local storage - here is an article about how to use it https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/
2. set the token as a cookie - which is my preferred method because a cookie cannot be accessed from a third party

Comment: Awesome so my next step is to learn how cookies work! I assume that when you create logout functionality you can delete the cookie and redirect the user back to the login page? Thank you so much for your time good sir!

Comment: @Jacexecaj _"you can delete the cookie"_ No, you can't delete the cookies mentioned in the answer. The answer describes cookies that aren't accessible by JavaScript. You can't read, modify or delete them in the frontend. There are cookies that are accessible in the frontend, but these cookies don't have the described security feature.

Comment: _"which is my preferred method because a cookie cannot be accessed from a third party"_ That's not completely correct. Only cookies with [HttpOnly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) flag can't be accessed by third-party libraries. Other cookies are equivalent to session storage or local storage, completely accessible by JavaScript.

Comment: Gotcha! So these cookies are set on the backend correct? I just want to make sure I understand correctly. I would stash the token in a cookie but how would I send it with my future fetch requests from the front-end if I cannot access them with javascript?

Comment: @Jacexecaj The browser will automatically send all the cookies with each request, even though they're not accessible by JavaScript. But only the backend can modify (and delete) with HttpOnly flag. On the other side, cookies without HttpOnly flag can be modified, read and delete in the frontend, but they are considered a security risk.

Comment: Gotcha thank you so much I will dive into learning about cookies.